# How to loop an array by passing it an object in the foreach

Tags: php, loops, class, object, foreach

*First of all, excuse me my ignorance, but I don't know how to explain this (maybe the title of this question is not correct).*

**My program:** I have created a class and its purpose is to create a table based on the parameters passed to the instantiated object (this connects to the database).

**What I don't know how to do it:** I need to access the position of my array (based on the values passed to me) within a for each.

**What I did:** If i type manually the values (`usuario`, `apellido1`, `apellido2`, `email`), my table is generated, but I'm trying to do this dinamically. I tryied with this line of code: `$r->myObject->tableFields` but I think, this, syntactically is not correct.

Code portion:

```
foreach ($res as $r){
    $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<td>' . $r->$myObject->tableFields . '</td>'; # This code not works
        // $html .= '<td>' . $r->usuario . '</td>';        # This code works
        // $html .= '<td>' . $r->apellido1 . '</td>';      # This code works
        // $html .= '<td>' . $r->apellido2 . '</td>';      # This code works
        // $html .= '<td>' . $r->email . '</td>';          # This code works
    $html .= '</tr>';
}
```

Full code:

```
<?php

    global $DB;
    
    class GenerateCrud {
    
        // Properties.
        
            public $tableName;
            public $id;
            public $tableFields = array();
    
        // Constructor.
        
            function __construct($tableName, $id, $tableFields){
                $this->tableName = $tableName;
                $this->id = $id;
                $this->tableFields = $tableFields;
                
                //is_string($tableName) ? $this->tableName = $tableName : $this->tableName = null;
                //is_string($id) ? $this->id = $id : $this->id = null;
                //is_string($tableFields) ? $this->tableFields= $tableFields : $this-$tableFields = null;
            }
    }
    
    $myObject = new GenerateCrud('users_test', 'id', ['usuario', 'apellido1', 'apellido2', 'email']);
    
    // Parse array to string.   
    $myStringArray = implode(",", $myObject->tableFields);
    
    $sql = "SELECT $myStringArray FROM $myObject->tableName";
    $res = $DB->get_records($sql);

    // Generate HTML - START
    
        $myArrayLength = count($myObject->tableFields);
        
        $html = '<table>';
            $html .= '<tr>';
            foreach ($myObject->tableFields as $ths){
                $html .= '<th>' . $ths . '</th>';
            }
            $html .= '</tr>';
            
            foreach ($res as $r){
                $html .= '<tr>';
                    $html .= '<td>' . $r->myObject->tableFields . '</td>'; # This code not works
                        // $html .= '<td>' . $r->usuario . '</td>';        # This code works
                        // $html .= '<td>' . $r->apellido1 . '</td>';      # This code works
                        // $html .= '<td>' . $r->apellido2 . '</td>';      # This code works
                        // $html .= '<td>' . $r->email . '</td>';          # This code works
                $html .=   '</tr>';
            }
        $html .= '</table>';    
    
    // Generate HTML - END
        
        echo $html;
?>
```

How could I do this, guys? I'm not looking for the solution, just some help or some advice on how to go about it.

I've been searching the internet for a while but I haven't found anything because I don't know how to describe my problem.

Thank you in advance!
Happy coding :)

Comment: Have you tried a `var_dump($r);` to see what the values are. As it looks like myObject->tableFields are actually properties of your objects

Comment: Yes! ```$r``` contains ALL values of my query. So, if I access to ```$myObject->tableFields``` I will get my 4 table fields because I'm in a loop (```usuario```, ```apellido1```, ```apellido2```, ```email```), but I can't mix this with ```$r->????```, do you know what I'm trying to say?

Comment: Use the second syntax version of foreach as shown here, https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php, then you have access to the keys _and_ values inside your loop body.

Comment: Thank you, you right, I have to modify a little bit my foreach structure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, $tableFields is an array so you have to iterate through it as well. So try this for your foreach loop.

```
foreach ($res as $r){
    $html .= '<tr>';
    foreach($myObject->tableFields as $field){
        $html .= '<td>' . $r->$field . '</td>'; 
    }
    $html .= '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Oh my god ... 2 loops ... Yes, I'm stupid. Thank you a lot man, now I know how to loop my program properly. Thank you again!